# Composer autoload can't find class

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to create a MVC structure and use composer to autoload everything.
But I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Init' not found in C:\wamp64\www\activity\Public\index.php on line 5

```
|MainFolder  
    |App  
    |Public  
    |Vendor  
        |ACT  
        |composer  
        |autoload.php  
    |composer.json
```

#### composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/activity",
    "description": "descrip",

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.25"
    },

    "authors":[
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"
        }
    ],

    "autoload":{
        "psr-4": {
            "ACT\\": "vendor/",
            "App\\": "/"
        }
    },
    "config":{
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    }
}
```

#### App\init.php

```
<?php    
namespace App;

class Init
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Loaded!!";
    }
}
```

#### Public\index.php

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$init = new \App\Init;
```

#### \Vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php

```
<?php    

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    "ACT" => array($vendorDir . false),
    "App" => array($baseDir . '/'),
);
```

*Obs: Already did `composer dump-autoload`*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't manually put things in `/vendor`.
2. While adhering to #1, don't reference `/vendor` in `autoload`, the packages should all have their own fully-functionaly autoloaders that composer will find and use.
3. You need to specify more of the path in your autoload.

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "App/"
    }
},
```

Think of it like telling composer "look for things starting with the namespace `foo\bar\` in the following folder".

**Note**: The folder name doesn't have to match the namespace.

Eg: Following the suggested `Vendor\Package\` scheme for PSR/Composer

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "sammitch\\meatstacker\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

And then:

- `\sammitch\meatstacker\Client` maps to `src/Client.php`
- `\sammitch\meatstacker\Bread\Rye` maps to `src/Bread/Rye.php`
- and so on